# 'scrolling' is deprecated.ts(6385) html5 iframe

Tags: html, reactjs

When I using this iframe in react project, the visual studio code shows `'scrolling' is deprecated.ts(6385)`:

```
<div>
      <iframe srcDoc={formText}
            width="600"
            height="600"
            scrolling="no"
          ></iframe>
    </div>
```

what should I do to upgrade the scrolling style? I have searching from bing seems no one talk about this issue, does anyone facing the same issue?